# How to change Sublime Text 3 default notes sign?

Tags: sublimetext3

I have a `.sql` file,when I `ctrl`+`/`,will notes text as `-- note here`.
How to change default note sign to `#notes here`?

Comment: Did you try https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/settings.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create your own comments preferences file to overwrite the default. Select *Preferences > Browse Packages*. This should open your `Packages` folder. There open the `User` folder and create a file with the name `SQL Comments.tmPreferences` (only the extension is important) and the content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Comments</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.sql</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>shellVariables</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string># </string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START_2</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>/*</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_END_2</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>*/</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

As you can see this changes the value of `TM_COMMENT_START` to `#`. After saving the file the new comment char should work.

Answer (score -1):

The comment shortcut works based on the file extension, for have `#notes here` (# generated) we need to have file extension changed to a script file like .sh or .py etc.

Comment: but in `.sql`,`#` is better than `-- `